# Integrations of an iOS component in React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reactjs, react-native

I am new to the development of React Native, I know iOS.
Just want to know about few points:

1. Can we add iOS (swift or objective C) code in a React Native App?
2. Can we add React Native Views into the existing iOS app?

I have googled and got the examples which point to that 2nd one is quite possible and Instagram did it in edit profile screen.

But I cannot find examples where it's a React Native app and we introduces swift or Objective-C code in between.

Please if anyone knows of any links or examples available for Case 1, please do let me know about it.

2nd question:

- When we integrate react native with iOS, it will be through a bridge. Let's say I create an app in Swift, to get react native views in it, we have to go through 2 bridges, one converting Swift to Objective-C and then bridge between Objective-C to React Native. Is that correct? If yes will it be as fast as the native app?

Comment: Active Reading: [Native Modules Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) and [Integration with existing apps documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can do both of them

1.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html

2.

https://codeburst.io/integrate-react-native-into-an-existing-app-ios-87c947a16044
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

Comment: I got this. what do you think about the 2nd question?

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta I think it will be hard. React Native just is good if using it from the scratch.

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta I haven't do "integrate  react native with iOS" yet. So I'm not sure about the flow. But I can sure it will be complicated.

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta You can create bridging https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

Comment: @anhtu Thanks, I am able to create functions in objective c and call them from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Can we add iOS (swift or objective C) code in a React Native App

Yes, I was able to do so:-

1. I created a React Native project, compiled it and run it in the simulator.
2. Go to the iOS folder in directory structure in the project and open the .xcodeproj in xcode.
3. Create an objective c file (MyObjcClass) and make functions which you want to use in React.

> MyObjcClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface MyObjcClass : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

> MyObjcClass.m

```
#import "MyObjcClass.h"

@implementation MyObjcClass

// tells react bridge to bridge our created class
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (NSDictionary *)constantsToExport {
  return @{@"CreatedBy": @"Type any number and get Square"};
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(squareNumber:(int)number getCallback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
  callback(@[[NSNull null], [NSNumber numberWithInt:(number*number)]]);
}
```

Now we can call these methods in JS.
Below I will show how to call objective c in React.

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

// to import native code
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

var MyObjcClass = NativeModules.MyObjcClass;

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    number:0
  };

  squareMe(num) {
    if (num == '') {
      return;
    }

    MyObjcClass.squareNumber(parseInt(num), (error, number) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        this.setState({number: number});
      }
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.spaceBetween}>Objective C inclusion</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder="type a number ...." style={styles.input} onChangeText={(text) => this.squareMe(text)}/>
        <ListItem placeName={this.state.number}></ListItem>
      </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes we can do

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

const majorVersionIOS = parseInt(Platform.Version, 10);
if (majorVersionIOS <= 9) {
  console.log('Work around a change in behavior');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To bridge an iOS native module into React Native, you can follow along the [official instructions: iOS Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios).

To paraphrase the important parts:

1. Open your .xcworkspace file in your ios folder to open XCode
2. Select File > New > File
3. Select header file
4. Name the header and select your project and its tests as the targets

```
//  RCTCalendarModule.h
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
@interface RCTCalendarModule : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

5. Select File > New > File
6. Select Objective-C file. Name it the same as the header but with `.m` instead of `.h`. Select your project and its tests and targets

```
// RCTCalendarModule.m
#import "RCTCalendarModule.h"

@implementation RCTCalendarModule

// To export a module named RCTCalendarModule
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

@end
```

7. In your React Native App or component, import `NativeModules` and use your new method

```js
import {NativeModules, Button} from 'react-native';

const {CalendarModule} = NativeModules;

const onPress = () => {
  CalendarModule.createCalendarEvent('testName', 'testLocation');
};
```

Note: You will need to keep rebuilding your ios app as you iterate (eg. run `yarn ios` after making a change to the `.m` or `.h` files)

For your second question, you can also add React Native into existing iOS apps. Follow these [official instructions: Integration with Existing Apps](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps).